# Communication between Erlang Gen Server's

Tags: erlang

I am building a network router application using Erlang OTP framework.

In its process of running a Supervisor creates two genservers and each estagen_server:call(CurrentProcName,{BinEvent,UniqueTrxId,MdPid},infinity),blishes a tcp connection to two individual servers.

Now while running the application , It happens that one genserver receives a duplicate event , on such a case I want that event to be processed by the second gen_server .

For this , i am calling **gen_server:call(NextProcName,{BinEvent,UniqueTrxId,MdPid},infinity)**,

This function I am calling inside the gen_server module when the condition for duplicate event satisfies.

NextProcName :: It is the registered name for the second gen_server

**NOTE** :: the code remains the same for both gen_server's

The problem is I am able to duplicate events but the event is somehow not getting passed to the second gen_server :(

Please suggest If I am doing it in the wrong way or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can share the source, it would be appreciated.

Are you sure the message is really received or do you just not receive an answer?

The most plausible problem I see here is that you're forwarding a message in a synchronous manner. If it's not the case, then you can disregard my post entirely. For now, let's see how synchronous forwarding plays out:

```
 client          server1             server2
   |                |                   |
   >--- Msg1 ----> (ok)                 |
(waits S1)          |                   | 
  (ok) <-- Reply ---<                   |
   >--- Msg2 ----> (ok)                 |
(waits S1)          >----- Msg2 -----> (ok)
(waits S1)      (waits S2) <--- Reply --<      
(waits S1)      (Waits S2)              |

          *Stuff crashes*
```

This is not exactly clear, but it shows what's going on. Here `Server1` is basically still counting as processing the message `Msg2` to the gen_server behaviour, and will thus never read the reply from `Server2` that it is waiting for. This will usually end up in a timeout and crash.

The correct way to do this is to instead send an asynchronous call (a `cast`) from `Server1` to `Server2`, including the `From` variable so that`Server2` can reply with `gen_server:reply/2` to substitute itself to `Server1`. `Server1` should then return with a `noreply` tuple. This will free `Server1`'s process and it'll be able to keep on processing other stuff.

Comment: You surely dont give terrible advice :P.

Comment: I am really sorry that I cannot share the code at this point of time. But I will try My level best to explain the conditions as an answer in this thread instead of a comment.